# How to create a button in editing field of ComboBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qcombobox

The requirement is when we type something in ComboBox, an X button appears on the right side of this field (to remove what we have typed). How can I do this?

[image]

The result with `setClearButtonEnabled`

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to enable the `clearButtonEnabled` property of the `QLineEdit`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QComboBox combo;
    combo.setEditable(true);
    if(QLineEdit *le = combo.lineEdit())
        le->setClearButtonEnabled(true);
    combo.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

---

## Update:

You have to create a custom QLineEdit.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class LineEdit: public QLineEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    LineEdit(QWidget *parent=nullptr):
        QLineEdit(parent)
    {
        QAction *action = addAction(QIcon(":/clear.png"), QLineEdit::TrailingPosition);
        button = qobject_cast<QToolButton *>(action->associatedWidgets().last());
        button->hide();
        connect(this, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &LineEdit::onTextChanged);
        connect(button, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &QLineEdit::clear);
    }
private slots:
    void onTextChanged(const QString & text){
        button->setVisible(!text.isEmpty());
    }
private:
    QToolButton *button;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QComboBox combo;
    combo.setEditable(true);
    combo.setLineEdit(new LineEdit);
    combo.show();
    return a.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

[image]

## Another option: custom style

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class ClearLineEditStyle: public QProxyStyle{
public:
    using QProxyStyle::QProxyStyle;
    QPixmap standardPixmap(StandardPixmap standardIcon, const QStyleOption *option, const QWidget *widget) const{
        if(standardIcon == SP_LineEditClearButton){
            return QPixmap(":/clear.png");
        }
        return QProxyStyle::standardPixmap(standardIcon, option, widget);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QComboBox combo;
    ClearLineEditStyle *style = new ClearLineEditStyle(combo.style());
    combo.setStyle(style);
    combo.setEditable(true);
    if(QLineEdit *le = combo.lineEdit())
            le->setClearButtonEnabled(true);
    combo.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. Sorry I forget to say, there is a `.png` file for X button (let's say `x.png`). This button should have transparent background (exactly as the picture above). So I need to put this picture as the background for the button. Your solution show the standard X button which is not what I want. (I updated above)